# How float divs to two sides in razor view

Tags: html, css, asp.net-mvc, razor

I'm trying to view notifications on razor view. I used foreach loop to get the data from the model.I want to display both "invitations" and "Requests" divs on the view like in the two table columns.One invitation down after another invitation.one request down after another request..(in one column all the invitations and requests on the other).. i used css float to do this.. but in the divs get mix in the result..why is that? there are some othaer elements in the view like, nav bar,side bar etc...my code is as follows;

```
 foreach (var item in Model)
    {



        if (@item.CreatedBy == item.UserId)
        {
    <div style="float: right; width: 580px;">

        <div class="panel panel-info" style="width:500px;margin-right:50px">
            <a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</a>
            <div class=" panel-heading">
                <h3 class="panel-title">Notification @counter1</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="panel-body">
                <p>Event is created by yourself .Budget of the event is @item.Budget <p>

                    @if (item.IsAccepted)
                            {
                    <p>You have accept the invitation!!!</p>
                            }

                    @if (!item.IsAccepted)
                            {
                        <p>You haven't accept the invitation yet!!!!</p>
                            }

                    @{counter1++;}

                </div>
            </div>
            <br />
        </div>

        }


    else

    {
    <div style="width: 580px; float: left">
        <div class="panel panel-info" style="width:500px;margin-left:250px;">
            <a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</a>
            <div class=" panel-heading">
                <h3 class="panel-title">Notification @counter2</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="panel-body">
                <p>Event is created by @item.Email .Budget of the event is @item.Budget <p>

                    @if (item.IsAccepted)
                    {
                    <p>You have accept the invitation!!!</p>
                    }

                    @if (!item.IsAccepted)
                    {
                        <p>You haven't accept the invitation yet!!!!</p>
                    }

                    @{counter2++;}

                </div>
            </div>
            <br />
        </div>
        }

    }
```

Comment: you might be able to utilize :nth-child(even) :nth-child(odd) in css

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need is css attributes "**clear: right**" and "**clear: left**" for your div's.

**However**, once you use them you will find next problem - there will be vertical gaps between your div's on the right and left side. That is because you are placing new div's right into **body** element of html page in your foreach loop. To make it right, you should first create two containers (divs) to which you should respectively add your divs containing data.

**Unfortunately**, with your current implementation you would have to iterate over your Model twice - once to fill up the right container with divs, and then once again to fill up the left container.

**A better approach** would be to create a **ViewModel** containing two collectios of objects which you are currently using, e.g.:

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    public IList<MyModel> Invitations { get; set; }

    public IList<MyModel> Requests { get; set; }
}
```

and use it as your View's model

`@model MyApplication.Models.MyViewModel`.

With this approach, you also remove some logic from the view, which is a good thing.

Here is an updated code for your view using the ViewModel as View's model:

```
  @model MvcApplication1.Controllers.MyViewModel

@{
    int counter1 = 0, counter2 = 0;
}

<div style="float: right; width: 580px; clear:right">
    <span>Invitations</span>
    @foreach (var item in @Model.Invitations)
    {
        if (@item.CreatedBy == item.UserId)
        {
            <div>
                <div class="panel panel-info">
                    <a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</a>
                    <div class=" panel-heading">
                        <h3 class="panel-title">Notification @counter1</h3>
                    </div>
                    <div class="panel-body">
                        <p>Event is created by yourself .Budget of the event is @item.Budget <p>

                            @if (item.IsAccepted)
                            {
                                <p>You have accept the invitation!!!</p>
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                <p>You haven't accept the invitation yet!!!!</p>
                            }

                            @{counter1++;}
                    </div>
                </div>
                <br />
            </div>
        }
    }
</div>

<div style="float: left; width: 580px; clear:left">
    <span>Requests</span>
    @foreach (var item in @Model.Requests)
    {
        <div>
            <div class="panel panel-info">
                <a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</a>
                <div class=" panel-heading">
                    <h3 class="panel-title">Notification @counter2</h3>
                </div>
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <p>Event is created by @item.Email .Budget of the event is @item.Budget <p>

                        @if (item.IsAccepted)
                        {
                            <p>You have accept the invitation!!!</p>
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            <p>You haven't accept the invitation yet!!!!</p>
                        }

                        @{counter2++;}
                    </div>
            </div>
            <br />
        </div>
    }
</div>
```

Good luck :)

Edit: a quick lookup to how the page looks after using provided solution:
https://jsfiddle.net/nh8Ls531/